# How to sample discontinuous probability functions?

Tags: probability, density-function, random-generation

I fitted a pdf with CumFreq to data, and the best fitting pdf is a discontinuous function composed as:

```
    The cumulative frequency function is broken into :
     Gumbel standard (<P) and Gumbel mirrored (>P) : Breakpoint : P =    166
     X < P :  Freq = exp[-exp{-(As*X+Bs)}]
              As =   0.0118       Bs = -1.4769
     X > P :  Freq = 1-exp[-exp{-(As*X+Bs)}]
              Ag =  -0.0046       Bg =    1.22
     Average X:    214     Median X:    144     St.Dev. X:  142.2
```

[image]

How can I sample thse two functions to produce random numbers? how can I make sure that the area under the curve equals 1?

Thanks!

Comment: One serious difficulty with the alleged CDF reported in the question is that it is not monotonic: it jumps *down* from 0.539 to 0.469 at $x=166$. There must be some mistake in reporting it.  What connection do `Ag` and `Bg` have to `As` and `Bs` in the second half of the equation?  The plot of a CDF shown in the illustration (as a solid black line) is not discontinuous, BTW.

Comment: Not sure really, just copied the info from CumFreq. Are you sure? I did the math in Matlab and I see no such jump down.

Comment: I did the math too, assuming `Ag` meant the same as `As` in the equation immediately above it and `Bg` meant the same as `Bs` in that equation. At best, the output is obscure.

Comment: Well good point, I assumed that the program knew! I'll dig more into it. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an estimator of the cdf (so it does not sum up to 1). Now, in order to draw a sample you need to generate variables $X_1,X_2,...,X_n$ uniform on $[0,1]$ and find the $Y_i = F^{-1}(X_i)$, where $F$ is the estimated cdf and by $F^{-1}$ I mean the inverse function. Then $Y_i$ are your variables.

You can think of this procedure as drawing a uniform variable on the $y$ axis, drawing a horisontal line through that poin and checking where does it cross the $F$. The '$x$' coefficient of the cross is the generated variable.

Comment: A CDF does not have to "sum up" to $1$: its integral will always diverge.

Comment: Agreed, I was referring to the pdf actually. Thanks!

Comment: But the functions presented in your question, Oliver, clearly represent the CDF. Those formulas guarantee it will have asymptotes at $0$ to the left and $1$ to the right, so there is no problem related to being an estimator, contrary to what is suggested in the first line of this answer.